# Is there a reason why my ArrayFormula is not working in the other cells of my column?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google sheet with form responses, I made an additional column where I want to look up from each submission if the value left of my new column already occurs in a range on another sheet.
So this is going to be a Vlookup formula finally. 
Unfortunately, I didn't make it to the Vlookup part yet because the ArrayFormula part is not working. 
I started off by looking to the cell value at the left with this formula, which worked, but the ArrayFormula part of it DOESN'T work.

```
=ArrayFormula(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1)))
```

I know that some functions don't work very well with ArrayFormula,
But I don't see any reason here this should not work because it's only looking to its row and its column.

I hope the image shows the problem well enough

[image: Snippet from screen]

Comment: Indirect() can't be iterated over an array. Maybe there other ways to achieve what you want?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of functions that don't work with ArrayFormula, but I can't find a blacklist of functions to avoid, so I've been doing just try and error with growing frustration. The only way I think I can make it to work is to paste in the formula with a script, triggered at FormSubmit, but this not so reliable I'm afraid, especially because I'll be having, in the  long run, more than 100 forms connected to this one spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to repeat the values from the previous column (let's say column A, starting in row 2), you can try in column B (also in row 2)

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), A2:A,))
```

Change range to suit. See if that helps?

UPDATE: To repeat the previous column (anywhere you input the formula) try (in row 2)

```
=offset(A1, 1, column()-2, rows(A1:A))
```

To 'limit' the output you can use any number instead of rows(A1:A) or replace it with COUNTA(A1:A)...

Comment: The only consistent thing here is that the reading column is always on the right of the source column. The formula must work regardless of where this pair of columns is located.  This is why I was using  ROW(), COLUMN() so that the formula can determine its own position first.

Comment: I posted a second formula. See if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this, which will search for specific header across entire sheet and then return values of that column:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&
 ADDRESS(1,       MATCH("job ID", Sheet1!1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(1000000, MATCH("job ID", Sheet1!1:1, 0), 4))}, 
 "select * where not Col1 matches 'job ID' and Col1 is not NULL", 0)
```

[image]

---

without sheet name:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(1,       MATCH("job ID", 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(1000000, MATCH("job ID", 1:1, 0), 4))}, 
 "select * where not Col1 matches 'job ID' and Col1 is not NULL", 0)
```

Comment: This could be a possible solution. I got your set up working, It reads the headers only in row 1 but this I could change to row 20, this will also be consistent through all my forms. On the other hand, the sheet name can't be hardcoded. I could have a cell on the sheet that holds the sheet name but I'm not sure if I'll get that to work :-(.

Comment: Without a sheetname it will only look at the active sheet? Because every Sheet will have a header named Job ID, just not always on a the same column but always on the same row?   As I have already stated, every cell in the reading (right) column have to be looked up in a known column in another sheet, so including this Vlookup function in your formula will bring me back to an ArrayFormula I believe, or do I see this wrong?